# Why doesn't my cookie get set

Tags: php, cookies

Im trying test the cookie that are set in my browser, earlier cookieid was given inside the url(mydomain.com?cookieid=1234). now im trying to set a cookie by calling the script which sets it. when i load the script known as proceed.php, i want that to go on and set the cookie as i have written. but it does not set the cookie as i intend

proceed.php

```
<?php

$cookieid = 1234;
include('bin/setcookie.php');

?>
```

setcookie.php

```
<?php
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../Lodread.php';

    $cookieid = isset($_REQUEST["cookieid"]) ? floatval($_REQUEST["cookieid"]) : 0;
    $project_id = isset($_REQUEST["projectid"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["projectid"]) : 0;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        $urlParts=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (isset($urlParts['query'])){
            $vars = parse_str($urlParts['query']);
            if (isset($vars['cookieid']) && floatval($vars['cookieid']) > 0 ){
                $cookieid = floatval($vars['cookieid']);
            }
        }
    }         
    if ($cookieid) {
        if ( ! isset($_COOKIE["cid"])){
            $cid = ($project_id?"$project_id:$cookieid":$cookieid);
            setcookie("cid", $cid, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", ".mydomain.com");
            header('Location: '.Config_Reader::readProjectConfig('Cookie')->base_url.'/set2.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what's the role of ".mydomain.com"

Comment: after the cookie is set it will show mydomain.com as the host

Answer (score 0):

This is sample, try like this.

**How to Get the Contents of a Cookie:**

Cookies set for a page can be retrieved from the variable $_COOKIE['cookie_name'] where 'cookie_name' is the name of the cookie you set earlier.

For example, if you wanted to display the value of the "userlogin" cookie, the following code should do the trick.

```
echo "Welcome back to the site" . $_COOKIE['userlogin'] ;
```

Note that you cannot set a cookie in PHP and hope to retrieve the cookie immediately in that same script session. Take the following non-working PHP code as an example:

```
/* WARNING: THIS WILL NOT WORK */
setcookie ( "userlogin", "anonymous", time()+60 );
echo "Value of userlogin: " . $_COOKIE['userlogin'] ;
```

Comment: i dont want to retrieve wall i want it to do is to just set the cookie

Comment: setcookie("TestCookie", $value, 0, '/', ".example.com"); try like this

Answer (score 0):

Try it without specifying the domain when using the setcookie function. Also, I would recommend passing $cid directly to your header function since the cookie value can't be retrieved within the same php script right away. Then finally you can see if the cookie is set for future use by using $_COOKIE['cookie_name'] in a separate php script to get the cookie's value.

Answer (score 0):

Set Cookie without "mydomain.com".
use this:

```
setcookie("cid", $cid, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/");
```

now you check cookie set.

Comment: mydoamin.com is essential since im checking the cookie

Comment: Even if you do use .mydomain.com for your site, you still probably want to set some cookies to *.mydomain.com so that they can also be read on a subdomain like abc.mydomain.com.